# Why do we use one bias (VCC) for transistor amplifier circuits and 2 supplies for opamp circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, single-supply-op-amp, biasing

Opamps are said to have 2 supplies, so that the output can rail between these two points, then why do transistors have only one bias point.

Comment: power rail and bias point are not the same. Also, there is plenty of transistor circuits out there that swing between a positive and negative rail, not just above ground.

Answer (score 1):

A supply rail and a biasing point are **different things**.

Some opamp circuits use a **negative** and a **positive** supply rail because sometimes that makes the circuit simpler.

Here are four basic opamp circuit, the inverting and non-inverting amplifier for both single and dual supply configurations:

[image]
[Source](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/op-amp-offset-for-no-reason-is-that-normal/)

Note how extra resistors and capacitors are needed in the "Single supply" circuits. The resistors are needed to create a 6 V DC voltage (to bias the opamp properly) and the capacitors are needed to block that same 6 V from reaching the input and output.

Using a negative and positive supply rails can also be done with transistor circuits. Many audio amplifiers do this, for example, this circuit contains no opamps but uses a +40 V and - 40 V supply:

[image]

[Source](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/100w-power-amplifier-circuit-using-mosfet)

Basically this circuit is a "power opamp" with feedback.

A biasing point is the current (or voltage) at which we **bias** a transistor. It is an operating point, for example we make 10 mA flow through a transistor and allow the **signal** to make that current vary between 5 mA and 15 mA.

This can be done with a single (usually positive) supply but also with a negative and positive supply. Which one is used is irrelevant to the biasing of the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Because an opamp is DC coupled and a common emitter amplifier is AC coupled. For the transistors to keep working the collector-emitter voltage must be positive. So the output cannot swing below the lower voltage rail.

The common emitter amplifier filters out the DC voltage.
[image: common emitter]
The C1 capacitor together with the R1 and R2 voltage divider network work like an adder. R1 and R2 specify the bias voltage \$V_\mathrm{bias}\$. Hence
$$V_\mathrm{base} = V_\mathrm{bias} + V_\mathrm{in}.$$
This way you can have a lower input voltage than the lower rail and keep the transistor operational.

Image taken from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html).

Comment: Could you please provide a link or citation to the original source of your graphic?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sure.